# Testing custom webservices

Tags: apex, webservices, unit-test, bestpractice, soap

I develop a custom webservice[SOAP] in salesforce and I want to test that webservice. Is a testclass ok for that custom webservice or should I test additional things.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking if you should do additional testing beyond a test class?

Comment: @DanielHoechst I am asking test class is suffcient for test the custom webservice or beyond that i have to perform anytype of testing..??

Answer (score 1):

The test class is good for making sure your code works when you deploy initially as well as when you deploy other changes that are seemingly unrelated.

I would also recommend using a tool like SoapUI to test to make sure the response is what you are expecting.

For both test classes and SoapUI, make sure to use assertions so you are verifying that the code does what you expect it to do.

Comment: if i want to do functional testing in salesforce how can i do that.any tools is there to do functional testing.

Comment: The only platform tool available are test classes. They are really kind of a mix between unit tests and functional tests. You can run them any time you want.